# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un evento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Quiero hacer lo siguiente en JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", () => {
     if (innerWidth < 768 && self.val() !== "") {
          self.parent().addClass("responsive-mode");
     }
});
$(window).on("load", window.onresize);
```

En este caso me devuelve `null`, pero lo que quiero obtener son las funciones que ejecutará el evento window.onresize. ¿Cómo haría en este caso?

Comment: Sería mejor que explicaras con palabras lo que quieres hacer y que incluyas un [mcve] Por otro lado, ¿A qué te refieres con obtener las funciones que se ejecutarán? ¿qué vas a hacer con eso?

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es obtener la lista de funciones agendadas al evento `resize` de `window`?